# Using triangulation for binning points in R^d

Tags: scipy, triangulation, binning, delaunay

I want to separate a given set of (not necessarily randomly distributed) points $$x_i \in R^d, i=1..n$$ into $$m << n$$ Delaunay-triangles, where each triangle approximately contains the same number of points.

Ideally the vertices for the triangulation are a subset of the points $$x_i$$.

For $$d = 1$$ quantiles fulfill the requirements, but it's unclear on how to extend this to more dimensions.

Any ideas?

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: None, because I don't know of any library providing such functionality. Scipy can do Delaunay Triangulation but it's unclear which vertices would create equal sized triangles.